# outlook emails from a particular user should be sent to sharepoint list or document library...:(

Tags: sharepoint-2007, outlook-2007

when a user sends an email from his id ex:aa to me, i want a way to configure my outlook so that all the emails from that particular user(aa) are redirected to sharepoint list or document library.....i have created some rules and stored all the emails in a particular folder but i want all those emails on sharepoint, when ever a new email arrives it has to update automatically......

please help me on this

thank you...

raj

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure incoming emails in SharePoint and allow this particular library to receive emails. Some pointers [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-sharepoint-services-help/add-content-to-sites-by-sending-e-mail-HA010086730.aspx).
2. Set outlook rule to forward emails from this particular ID to the Doc Library Eamil ID.